# Display differen divs on different resolutions with bootstrap

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

Basically, I'm trying to display a div with different wordpress post in a header as resolution changes (Actually trying to make that text responsive). But for some reason, instead of staying in the blue background header, it slides right beneath the header.

Live link here
http://soloveich.com/pr4/ 
The code

```
<div class="container-full" id="spbg">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-5 col-sm-12"><div class="visible-md visible-lg" id="gr"></div><div class="visible-sm visible-xs" id="grsm"></div></div>
    <div class="col-lg-7"><div class="visible-md" id="splmd"><?php
$post_id = 129 ;
$queried_post = get_post($post_id);
echo $queried_post->post_content;
?></div>
                      <div class="visible-lg" id="sptxt"><?php
$post_id = 127;
$queried_post = get_post($post_id);
echo $queried_post->post_content;
?></div> </div>
</div>
</div>
```

and css

```
#spbg {
  margin-top: 100px;
  color: white !important;
  background-image: url(http://soloveich.com/pr4/wp-content/themes/blain/images/spbg.png);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
#sptxt {
  padding-right:20px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: tahoma;
  font-size: 29px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 70px;
}
#gr {
 width: 417px;
 height: 283px;
 margin-left: 30px;
 margin-top: -60px;
 background-image: url(http://soloveich.com/pr4/wp-content/themes/blain/images/gr.png);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#splmd {
 color: #fff;
 font-family: tahoma;
 font-size: 20px;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-align: center;
}
```

At first, i thought it's text size, but after playing with font sizes figured it's not. Any other ideas on making that text responsive are appreciated as well

Comment: Doing this in CSS can be tricky because of all inherited values, I would recommend you do a basic jQuery script with resize() function and change the entire DIV class to the one you wan't this will work better because there will be no change in CSS view-port media screen.

Comment: hm. I'm not big on jquery, but i guess, time to look into it.

Comment: it is extreamly easy to do.. all you need is an IF statement that checks the width of your window and use .addClass .removeClass method. Use jQuery website for reference